# What to use ArrayList or LinkedList or TreeMap?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures

In my problem I have a large set of numbers. At run time I want to insert a number into this sorted series of numbers and grab the number which is next (Ascending next) to the inserted number (Everything is sorted) and then delete the inserted number.

There is one more constraint, sometimes The number I want to insert would be exactly equal to some other number in my initial set, in this case too I want to grab the next number.

I am confused whether I should use a TreeMap (As a TreeMap is always sorted, but comes with an overhead of a key) A LinkedList (Because entering and removing values becomes easier) or a simple 
ArrayList?

I am loading these numbers into memory and performing intense calculations, my platform is mobile and so I want something which is efficient. Any hints? So far I am using a Linked list although I am not facing any performance issues but I would want to speed up the process.

Comment: add to `TreeSet` and use `iterator`.

Comment: "performing intense calculation" is very vague - so it's not predictable, what kind of map/list you should use...

Comment: Intense calculations is a mix of looping through same operations again and again for which include the operation explained above as well as DB insertions, although I am using transactions to perform DB operations (insertions) These can vary from a few hundreds to a thousand. There is enough of code and putting that here will only increase the complexity.

Comment: do you want to use the list/map as a storage for your primary keys?

Comment: No I have to calculate age and predict age so I grab the current age and the date of start/ DOB feed it to a function then inside the function I compare the current age with the next highest element(in the list/ map/set) to it and predict that date. So for example my current age is 32 I insert it into the list and check the next highest value which is 40 I feed 40 to my calendar function with the calendar set to DOB/ start age of that thing and get the date when that thing will turn 40. Then insert this value into the DB. There are a lot of intervals I am calculating.

Comment: I would have used a TreeSet but it is averse to duplicates. So I am a bit skeptical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you really dont have to insert the number to get next number as anyway you are deleting it. In that case you can do something like this using a simple ArrayList itself for good performance

```
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst.add(1);
lst.add(2);
lst.add(4);
lst.add(8);
lst.add(15);

// Collections.sort(lst); // assuming list is sorted

// your key 
int key = 7;

// binary search to look for position where it would be inserted.
// if negative number does not exist so next number would be at ' -pos - 1' 
// if positive number exists so next number would be at 'pos + 1' 
int pos = Collections.binarySearch(lst, key);
pos = pos < 0 ? -pos - 1 : pos + 1;

// check for out of bounds as search for last number would give index out of bounds
pos = pos == lst.size() ? pos - 1 : pos;

// your next number
System.out.println(lst.get(pos));
```

Comment: good start so far, i hope this answer clears out, what @user2822178 is up to... i'm still not getting it, honestly... (i have a lot of guesses but no idea what he really (i mean REALLY) wants... )

Comment: @MartinFrank Thank you . Even i was confused what was required

Comment: aha - thanks as well, you +1 - you did it ^^ i'm glad you could provide this help!

Comment: Thansk guys, I am regretful if I could not explain my problem completely. But the above seems more efficient than my previous code in which I implemented a linke dlist.

Answer (score 1):

**Performance analysis of Collection classes**

```
Collection          Number of Elements
Class               5000   10000   20000

HashSet               10      20      20
LinkedHashSet          0      10      20
Vector               661    2714   10936
ArrayList            651    2694   10676
LinkedList           762    3305   28122
TreeMap             1021   10256   52719
HashMap             1712   12629   60050
IdentityHashMap      391    1532    7000
WeakHashMap         1572  failed  failed
Hashtable           3145   21261   89103
```

**Conclusion from the above result** :-

```
HashSet and LinkedHashSet maintained an almost constant performance level, while 
the number of elements doubled twice. They are perfectly designed for the search
operation.

Vector, ArrayList and LinkedList decreased their performance exponentially as the
number of elements doubles.

TreeMap, HashMap, IdentityHashMap and Hashtable decreased their performance 
exponentially as the number of elements doubles.

WeakHashMap is not reliable as mentioned in the JDK specification.
```

**For more details on performance of collection classes** :-

1. [Search operation performance on Collection classes](http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/Collection-Classes-Performance-on-Search-Operation.html)
2. [Big-O Complexities of Collection classes](http://javadevelopersenior.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/java_collections.pdf)
3. [Bog-O Complexities of Searching, Sorting & different Data Structures](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)